# Basic question on spaces

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm trying to learn LaTeX in my spare time using "Learning LaTeX" by Griffiths and Hingham.
I copied down the example code on page 6 and when I compile it there's no paragraphs.

Could someone point out where i've gone wrong? Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a short document to illustrate the basic use of \LaTeX.

Simply leave a blank line to start a new paragraph; indentation is automatic.

Mathematical expressions such as $y = 3 \sin x$ are obtaines with dollar signs. Equations can be displayed, as in 
\[
  y = 3 \sin x .
\]
Numbered equations are also possible : 
\begin{equation}\label{banana}
  y = 3 \sin x
\end{equation}
Because we have labeled this equation we can refer to it without having to know its number. Thus, the preceding equation was number~(\ref{banana}).

Powers (also known as superscripts), as in $x^2$ are obtained with \verb"^";
more complicated powers must live in curly braces: $x^{2+\alpha}$.

Likewise, indices (also known as subscripts) are obtained with the underscore: $y_3$ or $y_{n+1}$

We can get both indices and powers at the same time!
$x_{n_1}^{2+\alpha}$

\end{document}
```

Does it matter what text editor and compiler I use?
Sorry about how simple this question is but I can't find anything about paragraphs not showing up online.
I ran the compiler a couple of times as well, the paragraphs still arent showing up. Sorry if this is too basic a question for the forum, but I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: An empty line should cause a paragraph break. Try opening your `.tex` file in a different editor. Are the empty lines still there?

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is windows vs unix end of line characters, they might be interpreted the wrong way. The simplest way to check is to delete the whitespace between two lines and insert two new lines.

Comment: Ian : I've opened the .tex file in Texworks and Texniccentre, the empty lines are still there in both compilers but they arent there in the PDF.

hugo : I deleted all the whitespace in texniccentre then put it back in, the PDF didnt change.

Comment: there won't be any "empty lines" in the pdf from this file.  instead, the beginnings of paragraphs should be indented from the left margin.  that's the way typeset paragraphs are distinguished.  if the left margin is a straight line, then something *is* wrong, but that's not what this file should produce.

Comment: You have a wrong space before the colon: `possible :`

Comment: LaTeX defaults to zero additional skip between paragraphs.  To alter that, `\parskip 1ex` for example in your preamble will set the paragraph additional-skip to 1ex.  Likewise, the indent is controlled by `\parindent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As your paragraphs are mostly one line, the indentation doesn't show up so much, I marked the indented lines in red, and the non-indented lines in green,